# Get the first row in a table for each month on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `table` with many `records`, with `columns` like this:

```
under_symbol|quote_date|percent|type

under_symbol is a string,
quote_date is a datetime2,
percent is a float,
type is a char that can be 0 or 1
```

I need to get the first `record` in the `table` for a given month for each `under_symbol`, where `percent` > .19 and `percent` < .21 and `type` = 1

This returns all of them for each `under_symbol`, but I just need the first record of the month for each `under_symbol` that matches it:

```
SELECT * 
       [under_symbol]
      ,[quote_date]
      ,[type]
      ,[percent]
  FROM [Underlying].[dbo].[Table_EOD]
  where [percent] > .18 and [percent] < .22 and type = '1'
```

The problem is that I get lots of records for a given month. I just need the one which is the earliest in the month for each unique symbol, for each month, that matches those conditions.

Comment: Please show some sample data and desired results (as formatted text *not* images).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: <fantasy> If only there was a formal language for defining a table with columns of specific data types. Then one might add comments to explain usage and other helpful details. Hmm, DDL? </fantasy>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
with month_cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by eomonth(quote_date) order by quote_date) rn
    from [Underlying].[dbo].[Table_EOD]
    where [percent] > .18
          and [percent] < .22 
          and type = '1')
SELECT [under_symbol]
      ,[quote_date]
      ,[type]
      ,[percent]
  FROM month_cte
  where rn=1;
```

Comment: SteveC, your code works, but there is one problem, and I need to change the question because I realize I am not being clear, I need the first row for each under_symbol that matches that condition.

Comment: Actually, I think just adding  underlying_symbol to the partition statement does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *, 
row_number() over (partition by [month field], under_symbol order by [month field]) as first_record
from [TABLE NAME]
where percent > .18 and percent < .22 
    QUALIFY  first_record = 1 #if this part doesn't work try to do it in a CTE/ seperate sub-query
```